# how do i get data of the selected row in new form and user can edit it?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagrid

I have form that contain a datagrid I want that,
When user selected any row of the datagrid and click's to the edit button 
the data of the datagrid will opens in a new form and user can edit it and save.

sorry but i didnt get logic because Im entry level programmer.

How do i write a code on my '`EDIT DATA`' button
I have 9 fields on my primary form in datagrid.

I am using `sql server 2010 and vb2008`.

Comment: If it is WinForms, then it is probably a DataGridView (not DataGrd).  If the data is typed (easily done when the data is in a DataTable), then users can edit and add records in that DGV.  Not really a need to send them elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can just Google search "SQL SELECT and UPDATE" queries, however:

To select it, you need to use a query to select all of the information associated to that unique ID (Which you should have?).

Then, load it into a `DataTable`. Each control will be assigned it's value using the relevant `DataTable` data.

Then an update query will be run when you press Save/Update to update it.

Example `SELECT` Query

```
Dim Dt As New DataTable

    Using Da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Your_Table WHERE uniqueID=?", connectionstring)
        Da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = IDvariable
        Da.Fill(Dt)
    End Using
```

Then you need to use the `DataAdapter` to fill in the form controls, for example:

```
txtFirstName.Text = Dt.Rows(0).Item("firstName")
```

Then an `UPDATE` query

```
 Try
        Dim Dc As New OleDbCommand
        Dc.Connection = connectionstring
        Dc = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE Your_Table SET column_1 = ?, column2 = ? WHERE uniqueID=?", connectionstring)
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@column1", OleDbType.DataType).Value = control1.Text
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@column2", OleDbType.DataType).Value = control2.Text

        Dc.Parameters.Add("@uniqueID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = uniqueID

        Dc.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Edit Successful")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed to update data, refer to error log")

    End Try
```